# Angular4 - How do I refresh data from web-service in real time?

Tags: angular, refresh, observable

I am getting JSON data from web service. I currently have a web page that displays these data in real time, but does not display new value unless I refresh the page manually by pressing F5. How do I listen for new response and display recent data onto Html in real time? Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Thank you

**Component**

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
IntervalObservable.create(1000)
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.appService.getDataLN().subscribe(resLN => {
      //
      ];
      names.forEach(name => {
        this.findLastValueLN(resLN, name);
      })
    }, error => console.log(error))


    this.appService.getDataLS().subscribe(resLS => {
      let names = [
       //
      ];
      names.forEach(name => {
        this.findLastValueLS(resLS, name);
      })
    }, error => console.log(error)
    )}


  findLastValueLN(resLN, name: String) {
let index = resLN.Object.Table.findIndex(d => 
d.objectName[d.objectName.findIndex(objectName => objectName === name)]);
if (resLN.Object.Table[index].objectName == "status") {
  if (resLN.Object.Table[index].LastValue == "on") {
    let index_A = resLN.Object.Table.findIndex(actual =>
```

**html**

```
<div>{{this.arrLN_[0]</div>
//expected arrLN_[2] to be printed only when status is off.. 
<div>{{this.arrLN_[2]</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something you are looking for?

```
ngOnInit(){
    IntervalObservable.create(1000)
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.appService.getDataLN().subscribe(res => {
                let names = [//some name fileds that I need to serach from JSON];
                names.forEach(name => {
                    this.findLastValueLN(res, name);
                })
            }, error => console.log(error););
            this.appService.getDataLK().subscribe(res => {
                let names = [//some name fileds that I need to serach from JSON];
                names.forEach(name => {
                    this.findLastValueLN(res, name);
                })
            }, error => console.log(error););
        }
      });
}
```

This will bascially poll your backend every second and update the results. :)

Might also want to look at the .takeWhile observable modifier, to make sure that code will run only when that component is active.

Comment: so I have multiple subscriptions. Do I initialize this just at the beginning ngOnInit? or do I need to do this for every subscriptions?

Comment: Basically, you can think of the http promise->subscription model in angular, as a single backend call. It creates ajax request, executes it, returns and assigns data and closes itself.
To refresh data, you need to create an observable, that will basically tell the component to "restart" whole process.
You can put multiple subscriptions into that "timer observable", it will basically mean they will all be restarted at the same time. Or you can create multiple timers, if for ex. you need to assign them different frequencies. (ie. restart one every sec, but restart the other one every 3 secs)

Comment: so i have two separate http.get.request to pull out data from different end points, and two subscriptions in component.ts. But I still didn't see changes in my html..

Comment: Do you mean two subscriptions like this.appService.getDataLN().subscribe, or two timed subscriptions (with IntervalObservable)?

Comment: two timed subscriptions .getDataLN().subscribe and .getDataLW().subscribe

Comment: It should be nested subscriptions. Updated my code. :)

Comment: do I need to use res for both subscription?

Comment: Yes.. i guess it doesn't matter to set it as two different variable? it's still not working btw

Comment: The name can be anything that fits the regular "variable rules" (no reserved words, etc.) really. In fact those are two different variables, even with same name, cause they both are created only localy (only inside the =>{} block next to them).

Comment: If its still not working, put your code up on jsfiddle or similar service and i'll try to help you.

Comment: Hi, I updated my code. Please refer to updated post. Basically I encountered with another problem when printing them in html. First of all, when I have console.log in my service.ts, I can see that updating on chrome console, but it doesn't affect my html unless I refresh. Also  I didn't expect this.arrLN_[2] to be printed unless the status is off but I started seeing that value with arrLN_[0] (which I expected to see) when I binded all those subscriptions in IntervalObservable.

Answer (score 1):

you can declare a variable in your component:

```
result = Observable<any>;
```

and then call the service that way:

```
this.result = myservice.getDataLN();
```

in your html file, you can use async pipe to display always the new value without subscribing in the component.ts, so you will have this in your html file:

```
{{result | async }}
```